# Creating a group in trying not to use Sudo nor 777

Tags: security, unix, permissions, sudo

**How can you create a group such that I can use programs of another user in the PC in my user account without 777 permissions nor with `sudo`?**

I created a new user by `sudo adduser masi`.
I need either to change each program's permissions to be 777 at /usr/bin OR to use `sudo` to run each program.

However, both of these ways are awful for security and usability.
I apparently should be create a group `brothers` and then assign which program both brothers can use without `sudo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(disclaimer: logged in to windows at the moment)
Create a group

```
addgroup SomeName
```

Then add each user to the group

```
usermod -G SomeName,other,groups user1
usermod -G SomeName,other,groups user2
```

Change the permissions on the file

```
chgrp SomeName theFile
chmod g+rx theFile
```

Comment: `addgrp group me` is clearer as your second set of commands.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add write permission to a binary to execute it. You could just make them 755 root:root. If you want to restrict the programs to all but a group, you could chmod 750 and chgrp them to your new group.

Comment: I have everything 755 root:root, but programs do not work.

Comment: What is the error message?  And which OS?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be messing with the permissions in /usr/bin - your distribution manages that, all programs in that directory owned by `root`, and have 755 permissions.

If you want to have programs that both you and the one other user can use, but that other users can't, then create a different directory, add it to your PATHs and set permissions appropriately.

I think you need to provide the error messages you are seeing, because 755 permission is sufficient to execute a program.

Answer (score 0):

Permission 777 (rwxrwxrwx) would also imply write permissions for everyone, and that is not needed in any case in order to execute a binary. The permission that matters is the x-permission - the least significant bit in each 3-digit octal mode number (7=111 aka rwx). To run a binary you also need read permission.

Normally the permissions of programs installed in /usr/bin are already set so that they are executable for everyone (normally owned by root, group root, permission 755 or 555), so unless you have made some special changes yourself, there should not be any need to do anything.

Check the permission for the binaries in /usr/bin, and unless it is different than 755 or 755 you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Another nice alternative is to use extended ACLs (you will need to mount the relevant filesystem with the 'acl' flag)

Using acls will allow you to grant/deny individual users/groups specific access to files/directories without having to add a groupset for each 'seperation of rights/permissions'

man getfacl, setfacl, chacl for more info, however simple put:

**Granting an additional user (lisa) r-x (read/execute) access to a file**

```
          setfacl -m u:lisa:rx file
```

**Removing a named group entry from a file's ACL**

```
          setfacl -x g:staff file
```

Hope this puts you on the right track......